# How to disable a div and all elements inside div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, html

My problem is, I want to disable div. I ma not getting a way to do it.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<div ng-click="somefunction()">{{some value}}</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 $scope.items = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

I want to disable all div having even value.

Comment: Div's done have a disabled state. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You should use ngShow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

remove onclick from div as shown below

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" class="divList">
   <div>{{some value}}</div>
</div>
```

use `.filter()` to find div with even values and detach click handler

```
$(function(){
   $('.divList div').click(somefunction());
   $('.divList div').filter(function(){
        var value  = parseInt($(this).text()) || 0;
        return (value % 2 ==0);
   }).off('click');
});
```

Comment: This isnt the angular way - the item should be passed into the click function and the check done there

Comment: This is truly bad practice with Angular.

Comment: ..and let me count the ways: (1) `someFunction()` needs to be called with `$apply()` - it is not clear from the answer (2) It is assumed that Angular will have run and then jQuery will do its work; breaks if this view is shown after route change (3) In the general case where `$scope.items` may change, the HTML *will* change but the event handlers will be left in an unspecified-random state (4) Demands jQuery, while it can be done without it (5) It is inefficient even for jQuery! Why assign a click handler and then remove it, just negate the filter predicate and assign the click handler once.

Answer (score 1):

Divs cannot be disabled by HTML. You can do it by code:

```
<div ng-click="somefunction(item)">{{some value}}</div>
```

```js
$scope.somefunction = function(item) {
    if( item % 2 === 0 ) {
        return;
    }
    // rest of logic as before
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant disable div. but you can disable link or button like:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <a ng-click="somefunction()" ng-disabled="disabledEvenItems(item)">{{some value}}</a>
</div>
```

Or you can add style base on it:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
   <div ng-click="somefunction()" ng-class="{{'myClass': disabledEvenItems(item)}}">{{some value}}</div>
   </div>
</div>

$scope.disabledEvenItems = function(item) {
    return item % 2 !== 0  
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To run the function only for odd values you can use `$even` / `$odd` helper properties `ngRepeat` offers:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div ng-click="$even && somefunction()">{{some value}}</div>
</div>
```

**UPD.**

Angular way of doing what you are after is to use expression like this:

```
<div ng-click="item % 2 && somefunction()">{{some value}}</div>
```

Comment: This isnt true, you cant ensure that the values will be in numerical order like he wrote.

Comment: @JsIsAwesome I think you misunderstand what `$even` means. It's *"true if the iterator position $index is even (otherwise false)."* So it doesn't matter what array is being iterated, numbers, strings, objects, etc.

Comment: Yes, but i think he doesnt want the index to be even, he wants the number in the array to be even. for example [10,21,23,0], only index 1 and 2 are even.

Comment: Ha, maybe I misunderstood, and your question is correct then! Let's wait for OP's clarifications though.

Comment: He needs to tell us what he wants :)

Comment: I got my answer.This answer is not what I want, but I learnt new way to  call function inside ng-click.

Comment: @ng_developer Good! However be aware that the solution you picked is not the best in terms of best practices: you should not mix jQuery and angular code.

Comment: This is what I am thinking. But I accepted it as it solved my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:none`

```
<div id="someId" style="display: none;">
```

- `visibility: hidden` hides the element, but it still takes up space in the layout.
- `display: none` removes the element completely from the document, it doesn't take up any space.